# Rounded rectangle button's image resize causes distortion

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have several rounded rectangle buttons on screen, and I'm setting their image property from my code:

```
[_btnCol[0] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:myImg ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The problem is, the images get distorted (pixelated) when the view is loaded.
The funny thing, they look awesome when they are highlighted (probably thanks to "**Highlighted Adjusts Image**" property).

I tried all view modes (Scale to Fit, redraw etc).
I tried setting the image as the backgroundImage and still got pixelated.
I tried `[_btnCol[0] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];` and other content modes and still got pixelated.
I tried setting button type to custom and still did get pixelated, while it displays perfectly when I highlight the button.

So, is there a quick & dirty way to make these images look the way they should by easily -not needing to write many lines of code or embedding an imageview onto the button- having them resized correctly as the highlight adjustment does?

Thanks :)

Comment: Chances are you are using an icon library and the pixelated icon file you are getting does not have 2x at the end. When the image gets adjusted, the iOS appropriately fetches the 2x icon size and gets rid of pixelation on retina display. Change the file name you are using to fetch the icon file to have @2x or similar before file extension

Comment: Nope, the file doesn't have a 2x version and is not from an icon library.